# Behavior of uninitialized local char?

Tags: c++, gcc, char, undefined

If you have lets say a local `int` that is uninitialized, then its gets an undefined value but if you have a local `char` variable should that not have an undefined value as well? Of course 0 could be that undefined value, but i was wondering if char is any different, since all related info i find is about `int` and the program below just outputs 0 when the char variable is cast to an int. Im using GCC 4.7 with no flags.

```
int main()
{
char test1;
int test2;

std::cout<<test2; //garbage
std::cout<<std::endl;
std::cout<<(int)test1; //0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For built-in types, a local that you don't initialize contains an unspecified value. Using it gives undefined behavior.

Comment: I consistently [get 8](http://liveworkspace.org/code/32237210c3e9f43f39fb7b081ce9ea03), which is just as meaningless as consistently getting 0.

Comment: @underscore_d you are failing to distinguish `char` from `unsigned char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninitialised means really uninitialised. Just because you consistently get a particular value on *your* machine at a particular time, doesn't mean that will always be the case all the time on all machines.

You can verify that nothing is initialising your variable by dumping the assembly code for your function and inspecting it.

Answer (score 3):

> > If you have lets say a local int that is uninitialized, then its gets an undefined value

No, that isn't the right way to think about it. Your local variable doesn't get an undefined value, it gets no value whatsoever. Subsequently querying such an uninitialized variable invokes *undefined behavior*.

Your program won't necessarily print "0". It won't necessarily print *any number*, or even *anything at all*. Granted, on typical computers, using typical compilers, your program will print some number, but within the scope of the C++ language, we can't make **any** prediction about what your program will do or not do.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables get their initial values from whatever random data is in the stack space they occupy at that moment.  There is no guarantee that space contains zeros.

Comment: While this is true in practice, there's nothing in the C++ standard that *requires* this behavior. Undefined behavior really means "anything can happen".

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Such concise and accurate comment is what "newbie " like me truly needed :-)