# Why is the first digit of a string still read and output in a while loop where the condition !isdigit is false?

Tags: c++

**Note**: I know the solution that would solve the issue, but **I don't understand the "computer logic," or what is going on behind the compiler**.

In my C++ textbook, there is a blurb of example code that reads:

```
cout << "Enter a line of input:\n";
char next;
while ((!isdigit (next)) && (next != '\n'))
{
  cin.get (next);
  cout << next;
}
cout << "<END OF OUTPUT>";
```

... Paired with the example input: `I'll see you at 10:30 AM.`

I would expect, after typing in the input, for the output to be `I'll see you at <END OF OUTPUT>`. Instead, the first digit, "1," is also output, such that it becomes `I'll see you at 1<END OF OUTPUT>`. Why is this? Is this because the statement `cin.get (next);` is not declared/initialized outside of the while loop, and thus the first `next` value tested in the while loop's conditional parameters is not actually the first character of the keyboard input? Or does the while loop run an extra iteration when the next condition is not satisfied?

If it's the former, what does the computer test if `next` is not set to a value? And why does the first digit ("1") read still meet the condition to run the loop again one more time before terminating?

Comment: The first example does tests on an uninitialized value. At least assign *something* to `next` before testing.

Comment: This is not my code, I'm just trying to understand the logic behind what the computer is doing when it runs the code. What does the computer test when an uninitialized value is put in a conditional statement? As well, how come a digit will still be output when it doesn't satisfy the while loop's above condition?

Comment: If code uses an uninitialised variable then the behaviour of the program is undefined, which means any output at all (and any behaviour at all) is possible.

Comment: It's *undefined behaviour* which means the computer does *whatever*. There's no specific outcome that's guaranteed. It could crash, it could work, your computer could catch on fire, all that and more is possible. It's like saying "What happens when I keep driving on a flat tire?" Maybe nothing. Maybe something really bad. The general advice is to not do it because it's not safe.

Comment: In the initial example, the next character is read and then output and _then_ tested.

Comment: The first loop is, roughly, "test, read, print, test, read, print, ...", while the second one is "read, test, print, read, test, print, ...". You need a test between the read and the print, to achieve the expected output.

Comment: This is a serious mistake in the textbook then. If this is an indication of its general quality then you should throw it away and get a better one. Using an uninitialized value is undefined behavior so you can't reason about what the code will do.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations, I understand why the first digit is read now. One more quick question: since `char next` is declared (but not initialized) first, memory space must be allocated in the computer for the variable `next`, correct? So is the while loop's condition testing an empty value (null) in the first iteration, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to initialize `next` before using it, otherwise it is undefined behavior.

Now lets assume, `next` is properly initialized to a non-digit character. The condition `(!isdigit (next)) && (next != '\n')` is checked once when you enter the while loop and every time when you reach the end of the statement in curly braces. In your first version, you get a new `char` and immediately stream it to `cout`. The check is done afterwards and the loop terminates as expected.

Comment: Thank you (and others) for the explanation, I understand why the first digit is read now. I still have one more question, though: since `char next` is declared, memory space must be allocated in the computer for it. So is the above condition testing an empty value (null) in the first iteration?

Comment: @interjay Thank you for your comment, I changed it accordingly.

Comment: @ttoshiro The memory for `next` is allocated but it is not initialized to something meaningful.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12968024/8359552) for details.