# Segmentation fault - trying to pass matlab code to c ++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to pass a code that is in matlab for c ++ but it is giving segmentation fault (core dumped), can someone help me please?

Code in MATLAB

```
function strip = strips(strip,n,number_pixel)

se = strel('square', 3);
strip=imdilate(strip, se);

strip = imfill(strip);
[m1,n1] = size(strip);

vet=0;

for j=1:n1
    for i=1:m1
        if strip(i,j)==0
            vet=vet+1;
        end
    end
    aux(j)=vet;
    vet=0;
end

limite=uint8(number_pixel/4);

for i=1:n1
    if aux(i) < limite
        strip(:, i)=1;
    end
    if aux(i) >= limite
        strip(:, i)=0;
    end
end

end
```

Code in C++

```
Mat strips(Mat strip, int n, int number_pixel){
    int vet = 0;
    int limite = (number_pixel/4);
    int v[strip.cols];

    dilate(strip, strip, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3,3)));

    strip = imfill(strip);
    int n1 = strip.cols;
    int m1 = strip.rows;

    for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < m1; i++){
            if(strip.at<uchar>(i, j) == 0){
                vet += 1;
            }
        }   
        v[j] = vet;
        vet = 0;             
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        int j;
        if (v[i] < limite){
            strip.at<uchar>(i, j) = 1;    
        }
        if (v[i] >= limite){
            strip.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I already implemented the functions as imfill, I think my error is in the loop, but I can't find

Comment: I have no idea what any of that does but I see the use of an uninitialized variable j in the second loop. Don't know if that has anything to do with it

Comment: I have an array and I want to change only the i, keeping the value of j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to tell what the problem is, when not having a fully working example. One obvious problem with your code is, that you use `j` uninitialized in your second loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    int j;
    if (v[i] < limite){
        strip.at<uchar>(i, j) = 1;    // <- uninitialized j is used
    }
    //...
}
```

This is undefined behavior and basically everything could happen. `j` allocates memory but does not have a specific value. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967377/8359552):

> Local variables get their initial values from whatever random data is in the stack space they occupy at that moment.

That is `j` could be a very large integer and you try to access a value out of bounds. Or using `j` itself causes the error. As I said, the behavior is undefined.

**EDIT** I also think the second part of your code should be changed. `strip(:,i)=1` sets the ith column of the 2D array to `1`. Assuming that `strip.at<uchar>(i, j)` returns only a reference to a single value, your c++ code should be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    if (v[i] < limite){
        // go through all rows and set the i-th column to 1.
        for (int j = 0; j < m1; ++j)
            strip.at<uchar>(j, i) = 1;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have an array and I want to change only the i, keeping the value of j

Comment: Then just initialize ```j``` to whatever value you want to have, e.g. ```int j = 0``` or directly say ```strip.at<uchar>(i,0)```.

Comment: thank you very much, I was using 1, but for lack of attention I forgot that opencv uses 255